# Сетевой доступ к файлам Linux из Windows.

Tags: windows, samba, сеть, ubuntu, linux

Здравствуйте! Установил Linux Ubuntu 10.10, установил Samba, расшарил необходимые папки, но не могу из-под Windows с другого компьютера зайти в расшаренную папку, ошибка: сетевой адрес не найден, пробовал и \%compname% и \%ip%.

С Ubuntu на Windows в расшаренные папки заходит.

В чём проблема?

**Добавлено.**

У меня только 1 комп с Ubuntu.
Ошибка другая:

> Нет доступа к \%compname%. Возможно,
> у вас нет прав на использование этого
> сетевого ресурса. <...>

Пинг идёт.
В конструкции `\\%ip%` и `\\%compname%` используется двойной бэкслэш, не знаю почему хэшкод отрезает второй бэкслэш, когда я его тут пишу.

**Добавлено**

В настройках samba поставил доступ ко всем дискам, дал полные права (чтение и запись), учётку и пароль сделал.

**Добавлено**

Ещё при загрузке появляется сообщение о том, что служба Avahi была отключена, т.к. локальная сеть использует домен .local - что это значит?

Comment: Поправьте название вопроса на "Сетевой доступ..." что-ли, изначально сложилось впечатление что вы хотите из винды в линукс попасть на одной машине...

Comment: Не дошло написать так %)
Исправил, надеюсь кто-нибудь отзовётся

Comment: фаервол еще бы отключить на момент теста

Comment: система>параметры>samba config
а где в Linux файрвол?

Comment: А с ubuntu на ubuntu заходит? (smbmount и/или smbclient). Далее, что значит "сетевой адрес не найден"? Ping идёт? И ещё, в конструкции \\ip два бэкслеша или один?

Comment: Мне на другом форуме советовали переустановить систему, поставить Ubuntu LTS

Comment: он скорей всего про сторону винды, но это смысла не имеет. Вы дали доступ к расшареным папкам доступ только какому то юзеру? Если нет то дайте своему основному юзеру доступ и попробуйте в винде //%ipubuntu%/%shared_folder_name%

Comment: Выложите может smb.conf поглядеть?..

Comment: "Стандартный", тот который идет в поставке убунты из консоли выключается так:

     sudo ufw disable

А вообще, самба должна при установке в настройках файрвола создать файлик /etc/ufw/applications.d/samba со следующим содержанием:

[Samba]
    title=LanManager-like file and printer server for Unix
    description=The Samba software suite is a collection of programs     that implements the SMB/CIFS protocol for unix systems, allowing you to serve files and prin
    ports=137,138/udp|139,445/tcp

Comment: Открыл
    `sudo admin-shares`
в терминале, всё настроил что нужно.
Но локальный сетевой адрес машины получился `\\samba24`, есть ли возможность переделать в `\\ubuntu` ?

Comment: На будущее:
Меньше используйте ГУИшные настройки в Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Делаю вашу работу:**

1. sudo apt-get install samba smbclient smbfs
2. sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

Заполняем по следующему принципу(стандартный кофиг можно удалить, или сбекапить):

```
[global] //главная секция настроек
  workgroup = home //имя локальной группы
  netbios name = my system //нетбиос имя компьютера
  server string = my file server //строка инфо о сервере
  security = share //уровень доступа
  browseable = yes //возможность просматривать вложенные каталоги
[my_share] //имя шары
  path = /home/user/my_share //путь к расшариваемому каталогу
  comment = for all //комментарий к шаре
  readonly = No //только чтение (выкл.)
  guest ok = Yes //возможность работы с каталогом пользователей без учетной записи на сервере
```

Если хотите, что бы пользователи могли писать в каталог:

1. sudo chmod 777 /home/user/my_share
2. readonly ставим в yes

После проделанных операций:

```
sudo smbd restart
sudo nmbd restart
```

Или просто

```
sudo reboot
```

P.S. Все это есть на первой странице поиска, первая строчка. Собственно, когда мне нужно было, я там и нашел. **НЕ ЛЕНИТЕСЬ ВПРЕДЬ!**

По поводу "Локальная сеть имеет домен .local, служба avahi будет отключена...":

Про avahi читаем на вики, [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi)! Если не нужна, можно выпилить командой *sudo apt-get purge avahi-daemon*, только аккуратно, что бы ничего лишнего за собой не потянула.

Comment: Во-первых, если бы я нашёл ответ в поисковике, я бы сюда не обращался; во-вторых, надо не debian а samba, если бы ты внимательно прочитал.

Comment: Ну так всёже smbclient с ubuntы работает или нет? (Если нет, то искать уже меньше где)

Comment: debian - ОС. ubuntu - ОС сделанная на основе debian. Если перейти по второй ссылке в поисковике, там мануал настройки samba, который кстати работает у меня. И работает хорошо. 
Так, что если бы вы внимательней искали, то все бы замечательно настроили.

Comment: "Делаю вашу работу" - ну спасибо вам за такое одолжение..